# UITableView extend different background color below cells

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` that I have given a `headerView` that has a green background. I have also given the `UITableView` that same green background color so that when the `tableView` is pulled down it feels like a seemless color above the `tableView`. Works perfectly.

The problem is my `tableView` only has 4 rows, and below that it shows the green color again.

[image]

**How can I show white below the rows instead so that I only see the green background color when pulling down the `tableView`?**

Comment: Maybe adding a white tableview footerView?

Comment: @johan Tried that, but it just makes a block of white color (the view) and doesn't go into infinity below the cells like I would prefer.

Comment: Thank you for asking this question. I am here with the same situation as yours.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add an extra top view, same as in [this answer to *UIRefreshControl Background Color*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13394966/115200):

```
CGRect frame = self.tableView.bounds;
frame.origin.y = -frame.size.height;

UIView *bgView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
bgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

[self.tableView insertSubview:bgView atIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add a fifth cell with no content, and make it, say 400 points high, and limit the size of the table's contentView so that you can't scroll to the bottom of that cell.

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    self.tableView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.tableView.frame.size.width, 500);
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGFloat h = (indexPath.row == 4)? 400:44;
    return h;
}
```

Putting the contentSize setting in viewWillLayoutSubviews ensures that it will be reset to that value if you rotate your device.

Answer (score 0):

as I said in these comments, in this way the headerView will be under the navigationBar and if you pull down the tableview you will see the headerView green. So you can set white color for tableView:
(i tested it and work)

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {

    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    headerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    UILabel *lab = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -50, 320, 120)];
    lab.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [headerView addSubview:lab];

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;

} 


#pragma mark - Table view data source
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

  return 80;

}


-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

  return headerView;

}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
  // Return the number of sections.
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstood. Cells are white. TableView background color and headerView are green. Below the cells is also green because that is the tableView background color. But I want just BELOW the cells to be white as well.

Comment: @Nic Hubbard there is a misunderstanding. You would have only cell and headerview green right? And the rest of the table white?

Comment: No, cells are white. Please see my updated question with an example image.

Comment: @Nic Hubbard  ok, and if you create an headerview more high but show only what do you want, for example the view for header is 150px high and in delegate method of tableview you return 50 px? I dont try this but if this work you can give white color to tableview

Comment: @llario Sounds like a good idea, but there ins't a delegate method to set the `tableView` header height, it is just based off of how high the view is that you set to that property.

Comment: @Nic Hubbard for delegate i say: heightForHeaderInSection, and in this method return for example 50px, so if you pull down the table you should see the headerview green and not the white table view

Comment: That is for section headers if you are using a grouped table view. I am talking about a tableView.tableHeaderView.

Comment: @NicHubbard this is incorrect. that delegate method is not just for grouped table view. check my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

**Same as the accepted answer - in Swift 5:**

```
var frame : CGRect = self.tableView.bounds
frame.origin.y = -frame.size.height

let bgView : UIView = UIView.init(frame: frame)
bgView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

self.tableView.insertSubview(bgView, at: 0)
```

Also add the following code (right after the above code) to make sure it works for other sized devices:

```
bgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
bgView.autoresizingMask = [UIView.AutoresizingMask.flexibleWidth]
```